# How to include multiple language development header in C++

Tags: python, c++, ruby, libraries

I want to include the `Python.h` and the `ruby.h` header in the same C/C++ file, as I want to work with both at the same time. Which would be the best way to include both and prevent the compiler/preprocessor to warn about multiple redefinitions of the same variables or there is another way to use those languages from C?

MWE:

```cpp
// file.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <ruby.h>

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

I warnings like this from the preprocessor:

```
In file included from /path/to/Python/include/Python.h:8,
                 from /path/to/file.cpp:4:
/path/to/Python/include/pyconfig.h:61: warning: "HAVE_HYPOT" redefined
 #define HAVE_HYPOT

In file included from /path/to/Ruby/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:24,
                 from /path/to/Ruby/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from /path/to/file.cpp:5:
/path/to/Ruby/include/ruby-2.7.0/x64-mingw32/ruby/config.h:211: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define HAVE_HYPOT 1
```

Comment: Maybe post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help. Including your compile error.

Comment: I update the question, add a MWE and include the output from the compiler/preprocessor.

Comment: Make wrappers and include ruby/python.h in source file? Eg: PythonWrap.h + PythonWarp.cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example to demonstrate not getting complaint for redefinitions in headers.
Though you may have to re-declare every functions you need in a wrapper header.

P.h

```
#define AAA 2
```

R.h

```
#define AAA 1
```

Pwrapper.h

```
int get(void);
```

Pwrapper.cc

```
#inclide "P.h" //include here, so Pwrapper.h won't conflict definition with R.h
int get(void){
    return AAA;
}
```

In your actual source file for operations

```
#include "Pwrapper.h"
#include "R.h"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the headers and the library are pretty big and I don't think I could do it in a reasonable way

Comment: If there is no better answer, the best shot is handling operations of pyhton in `PythonWrapper` and outside just need to call a starting function.

Comment: As I get no more answers, I mark this as the answer. I got only one more question, where I suppose to include P.h?

Comment: @PillFall In Pwrapper.cc, I missed the include. My answer is edited. Include P.h in source file so it won't conflict with other header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats in python.h but since python is an interpreted language, Id assume python.h references object code that interprets python code which is held as a text data in your c++ code as in

```
char * pythonScript = "print \"Hello, World!\"";
pythonExec(pythonScript);
```

Python is an interpreted language (at least on linux) and is also a foreign languge to a c++ compiler.

The only time Ive seen c++ directly support a foreign language is the implementation dependent asm keyword where some compilers allow you to write assembly language code blocks directly into the C++ source code. Its not supported by all compilers and asm is the only time Ive seen this style of support.

Debateably, things like opengl are languages in their own right and there is a way of foreign language support in the sense that each opengl function and variable is replicated with a c++ function or variable to the extent that the full language is mapped into c++.

Sorry I dont have a full answer but given that I think what youre trying to do isnt really supported, I hope it provides you some pointers to where you should be looking.

Maybe someone has a better answer.

Comment: `Python.h` it's a library that's come bundled with Python [link](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), same as `ruby.h` [link](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/extension_rdoc.html), which as I understand, serve as an interface to use those languages inside C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

This does not work (as alluded in a comment) for preprocessor macros, which are not `#undef`'d, so does not answer the question exactly.

### Original answer

Not sure about linking / global variables within implementation files, or about what your files contain, but for header files, you can put the `include` macro within a namespace:

```
namespace a {
#include Python.h
}
namespace b {
#include ruby.h
}
```

Then you reference the proper namespace to use a variable:

```
a::SAME_NAME
b::SAME_NAME
```

Comment: That won’t work. The libraries that the headers describe don’t put their names in those namespaces.